# Jade conditionals inside the script tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, conditional-statements

I'm adding some Javascript to a jade template and the problem I'm having is code duplication because I can't do any jade conditionals inside the script tag. Is there anyway around this, code below.

```
if streamingType == 'HLS_IOS'
    script
        :coffee(bare=true)
         window.$j = jQuery
         window.player = new HtmlPlayer $j('#wrapper')
         player._loadVideoAt '#{url}'
else
    script
        :coffee(bare=true)
        window.$j = jQuery
        window.player = new FlashPlayer $j('#wrapper'), '#{flashPlayerId}'
        player._loadVideoAt '#{url}'`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use conditionals inside script tag in recent jade versions:

```
script
    | window.$j = jQuery;
    if streamingType == 'HLS_IOS'
        | window.player = new HtmlPlayer($j('#wrapper'));
    else
        | window.player = new FlashPlayer($j('#wrapper'), '#{flashPlayerId}');
    | player._loadVideoAt('#{url}');
```

Sadly, I didn't find any way to use conditionals and filters at the same time, so you might have to write plain javascript.